# Google Charts works in Preview but does not work in Force.com Site

Tags: visualforce, javascript, google-charts

I am using Google Charts to display some data from a custom Object, it displays the data when previewed, but when I access it from a Force.com site I cannot view the chart. Additionally when I use a wrapper class to store the Custom object field values in the class variable and then display it using a chart, it works in Force.com site as well as in Salesforce Preview. I looked at all the Field Level Security Settings as well as Object Security Settings, everything is read/write enabled for the Public user of the force.com site. I'm new to this, I feel like I'm missing something so obvious that even google cannot help. Can someone please point it out?

Comment: Which profile are you checking FLS and object settings ? It has to be guest user profile

Comment: I did check for Guest Profile, Public Access settings, every read and write for every field is enabled.

Comment: Where is js of the chart saved? cdn? or static resource? go to the dev tools and check in network if the site is getting the files required for google chart to work